# Convert stringLiteral into a string

Tags: scala

In Scala's parser combinators (`JavaTokensParser` in particular) there is a definition `stringLiteral` that matches a Java-like string.  Is there a way to convert a `stringLiteral` into a `String`?  For example, If I parse `"Run \" run \\ run"` I would want to convert the entered string literal into `Run " run \ run`.

Also, is there a definition for stringLiterals that also supports `"""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons provides a useful method: [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch you are asking a more complicated question, but just in case the simple answer is write your own parser and trim the quotes after the applicator, ^^.

In the REPL you can test it like such:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

object testParsers extends JavaTokenParsers {

  val aString : Parser[String] = stringLiteral ^^ { 
    case s => s.substring( 1, s.length-1 ) 
  }
}

testParsers.parseAll(testParsers.stringLiteral,""""Run \" run \\ run"""")
testParsers.parseAll(testParsers.aString,""""Run \" run \\ run"""")
```

I am not aware of any built in triple-quote parsers, so I guess you will have to roll your own.

Comment: This doesn't handle character escapes.  By the lack of answers it sounds like there's nothing built in, which is a pity.